# How to use a regular for in Angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, angular

So, I know there is the `*ngFor` to loop several times, but this loop only works with an array. Is there a way of doing this loop with number?

I'd like to:

```
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#">2</a>
<a href="#">3</a>
<a href="#">4</a>
<a href="#">5</a>
```

Like this:

```
<a href="#" *ngFor = "let pagina of paginas">{{pagina}}</a>
```

But I'd like to pass a number to `paginas`, instead of an array.

In PHP would be something like this:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: You can pass the index of the entry of the array, like so: `<a href="#" *ngFor = "let pagina of paginas">{{index}}</a>`. The index is available through Angular.

Comment: @PhilCap, thanks, but still my `paginas` needs to be an array.

Comment: <li *ngFor='#i of  [1,2,8,11]'>

Comment: @chris, thanks, but still my paginas needs to be an array.

Comment: This is so sad, such a powerfull tool but there is not a simple `for`...

Comment: yes, but as far I know it needs to be a collection.

Comment: I cannot see a use case where this is a problem. You can always generate a collection. Using lodash you can write the following `paginas = _.range(1, 6)` and then the result is almost as short. This is hardly a serious limitation.